# Delete unused/redundant SQL Agent schedules?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to delete unused SQL Agent schedules from SQL Server 2008?

If so, how?  I'm sure I'm missing something REALLY obvious!

Comment: Do you already have a list of unused jobs or do you need to find those as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the schedules that are redundant then it's just calling `sp_delete_schedule` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175050(v=sql.100).aspx - to remove

If you need to get a list of schedules not currently enabled, or attached to a job you'll need to go through the `sysschedules` and `sysjobschedules` tables in msdb

Disabled jobs are fairly simple to find:

```
select a.schedule_id, a.name, b.name
from msdb..sysschedules a
left join master..syslogins b on a.owner_sid=b.sid
where enabled=0
```

To find those that are enabled, but not attached to a job:

```
select a.schedule_id, a.name, a.owner_sid, b.name
from 
msdb..sysschedules a 
left join master..syslogins b on a.owner_sid=b.sid
where a.schedule_id not in
(select schedule_id from msdb..sysjobschedules)
```

I  include the owner name, so I can check for system schedules (owned by sa), as I can't see any other way to identify them (if anyone else can, I'd love to know).